# Implementing code for the following functions in gameBoard

Tags: c, arraylist, void-pointers

```
gameBoard *InitBoard(char *space, int nos,void (*toStringGameboard)(void *S), int (* getNumberOfSpaces) (void * S),char * (* getTypeOfSpace)(void * S))
    {
        gameBoard *gb= (gameBoard *) malloc(sizeof(gameBoard));
        strcpy(gb->typeOfSpace, space);
        //implement the function pointers
        return gb;
    }

    char * getTypeOfSpace(void  *board) {
        return ???;
    }
    
    int getNumberOfSpaces(void * board) {
        return ???;
    }

    void toStringGameboard(void * S){
    //print out something informative and cute
        return;
    }
```

I am very confused on void pointers. So far, for the first method, this is what I have.
Essentially, since I do not understand what is going on,
I've just repeated the parameters of the function in an attempt to initialize them.
Is this correct, if not where do I go from here?

```
gameBoard *InitBoard(char *space, int nos,void (*toStringGameboard)(void *S), 
          int (* getNumberOfSpaces) (void * S),char * (* getTypeOfSpace)(void * S))
{
    gameBoard *gb= (gameBoard *) malloc(sizeof(gameBoard));
    strcpy(gb->typeOfSpace, space);
    void(*toStringGameboard)(void *S);
    int(*NumberOfSpaces)(void *S);
    char(*getTypeOfSpace)(void *S);
    return gb;
}
```

For the second method, I'm thinking I can use char typeOfSpace[20], as written into gameBoard.h, but am not entirely sure how to go about that:

```
typedef struct gameBoard {
    char typeOfSpace[20];   //"WIN", "BACK", "FORWARD", "SAFE"
    int numberOfSpaces; //if the type of space is "BACK", "FORWARD", then this is the number of spaces to move
        int (* getNumberOfSpaces) (void * S);
    void (* toStringGameboard)(void * S);
    char * (* getTypeOfSpace)(void * S);
}gameBoard;

gameBoard *InitBoard(char *typeOfSpace, int nos,
                    void (*toStringGameboard)(void *S), 
                    int (* getNumberOfSpaces) (void * S),
                    char * (* getTypeOfSpace)(void * S));

char * getTypeOfSpace(void  *board);
int getNumberOfSpaces(void *board);
void toStringGameboard(void *board);
```

No clue on how to do the second two, any help would be excellent!

Answer (score 0):

In `InitBoard`, you're obviously suppose to inituialize the fields of `gb`.

```c
gameBoard *InitBoard(
   char *space,
   int nos,
   void (*toStringGameboard)(void *S),
   int (*getNumberOfSpaces) (void *S),
   char *(*getTypeOfSpace)(void *S)
) {
   gameBoard *gb = malloc(sizeof(gameBoard));
   strcpy(gb->typeOfSpace, space);
   gb->numberOfSpaces    = ???;
   gb->getNumberOfSpaces = ???;
   gb->toStringGameboard = ???;
   gb->getTypeOfSpace    = ???;
   return gb;
}
```

Turns out all the necessary values are provided as parameters.

```c
gameBoard *InitBoard(
   char *space,
   int nos,
   void (*toStringGameboard)(void *S),
   int (*getNumberOfSpaces) (void *S),
   char *(*getTypeOfSpace)(void *S)
) {
   gameBoard *gb = malloc(sizeof(gameBoard));
   strcpy(gb->typeOfSpace, space);
   gb->numberOfSpaces    = nos;
   gb->getNumberOfSpaces = getNumberOfSpaces;
   gb->toStringGameboard = toStringGameboard;
   gb->getTypeOfSpace    = getTypeOfSpace;
   return gb;
}
```

---

It's surely the intent to call `getTypeOfSpace` (etc) as follows:

```c
gb->getTypeOfSpace(gb)
```

As such, the `board` parameter of the others will really be a `gameBoard*`.

```c
char *getTypeOfSpace(void *board) {
   gameBoard *gb = board;
   return ???;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I have a follow up question. There's a similar function: Player *InitPlayers(char *name, void (* setPosition)(void * S, int pos), void (*toStringPlayers)(void *S), int (*getPosition) (void *S),char * (* getName)(void *S)){   
       Player *player = (Player *) malloc(sizeof(Player));strcpy(player->name, name);       
       //set up the function pointers                                                                                   
       return player; }

Comment: Wow that formatting was very bad, but I was wondering if there would need to be a player->positionInBoard = pos for the second parameter. I tried this and it ended up not working do I not need one for positionInBoard? I wasn't sure how it worked with setPosition having a different format of parameter.

Comment: I have no idea what `Player` is